# @SuppressWarnings value when having an Annotation as superinterface

Tags: java, annotations, suppress-warnings

I have an enum which implements an Annotation and I'm getting the warning:
The annotation type A should not be used as a superinterface for MyClass.

Is there a value for @SuppressWarnings which handles this warning?
I don't want to use @SuppressWarnings("all"), I'd rather have the warning than suppress all of them.

I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure you need to extend another Annotation? Annotations are not supported by the JVM like classes are, so you won't be able to get the same sort of inheritance.

Comment: It's not really my code so I don't have much say in it. I'm just working with it so I wanted to minimize the clutter.

Comment: Consider JAXB's iface AnnotationReader -- i think its only purpose is to allow 'detecting' annotations which "are not there". Then you want to create synthetic annot. instances. Without reflection, the easiest would be to just implement annotation interface. And then -- you get this warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no such value for the `@SuppressWarnings`. If there was such a value then the compiler would have given you a hint on using it along with the warning.

Since, it doesn't exist, it probably means that it isn't a good idea to make your enum extend an annotation.

And if you still want to go that way then I think `@SuppressWarnings("all")` is the only option you have.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. Just wanted to be sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("ClassExplicitlyAnnotation")
```

In IntelliJ you can open the context menu and select the "Suppress for class" option.

[image]